# How to pass all bash arguments to bash -c within command substitution?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, escaping

I am trying to conditionally pass script arguments to `bash -c`, which itself is passed to a `docker run` command. The example below illustrates what I am trying to do.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Args: ${@}"
docker run ubuntu \
  $( if [[ ! -z ${@} ]]; then echo "bash -c ${@}"; fi )

docker run ubuntu \
  $( if [[ ! -z ${@} ]]; then echo "bash -c \"${@}\""; fi )
```

For a call `./myscript.sh ls -la`, this gives me the following output.

```
Args: ls -la
bin
boot
dev
etc
home
lib
lib32
lib64
libx32
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
-la": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-la": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

As you can see, the first `docker run` call works, but ignores the `-la` flag that has also been passed. I thought about trying to enclose the command passed to `bash -c`, namely `ls -la`, in escaped quotes, but this doesn't work at all.

How can I realize the desired behavior? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You basically are doing a

```
bash -c ls -la
```

You can reproduce this, if you are doing the same command on the command line: It would give the same result.

From the bash man-page about the `-c` option:

> ... commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are  arguments  after  the  command_string,  the first  argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.  The assignment to $0 sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

Therefore, the `-la` is not passed as argument to `ls`. You would have to do a

```
bash -c "ls -la"
```

If I understand your code correctly, you don't want run the arguments on docker, if the argument list is empty. I would then try a

```
(( $# > 0 )) && docker run ubuntu bash -c "$*"
```

Comment: Yes, that's why I already tried to add escaped quotation marks around the `$@`.

Your suggestion would work in the simple example case that I posted here, but my actual use case is a much longer `docker run` command with many more of similar conditionals.

Basically a `docker run`, where options are added depending on certain environment variables. Using your suggestion, I think I would have to duplicate the entire `docker run` command. Think your suggestion, but I also want to run it without the `bash -c`, if the conditional is not fulfilled.